# Parent-child z-index issues (inside a container)

Tags: html, css, reactjs, z-index

I am having problems with my child not appearing over my parent even though it has a higher z-index than the parent. Both images appear in Inspect > Elements so I'm sure its not that problem. The child conditions are also being passed to the browser so that is also correct.

This is the relevant CSS snippets:

```
.game-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 490px;
  height: 850px;
}

.player-sprite {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  background-image: url('./sprites/Player.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.player-sprite.game-over {
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url('./sprites/Player_lose.png');
  z-index: 100;
}

.player-sprite.game-won {
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url('./sprites/Player_winning.gif');
  height: 80px;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

This is Player.js where the logic is in:

```
import React from 'react';

const Player = ({ playerX, playerY, direction, isMoving, gameOver, gameWon }) => {
    let statusClass = '';
    
    if (gameOver) {
        statusClass = 'game-over';
    } else if (gameWon) {
        statusClass = 'game-won';
    }

    const className = `player-sprite ${direction} ${isMoving ? 'moving' : 'stopped'} ${statusClass}`;

    return <div className={className} style={{ left: `${playerX}px`, bottom: `${playerY}px`}} />;
}

export default Player;
```

This is what happens when gameOver condition is met in browser and every style not strikethrough-ed is checked (background-image is detected by browser but it won't appear)

[every style not strikethrough-ed is checked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2J7Vd.png)

And when I uncheck the missing child, the parent appears.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoP6J.png)

Btw, the game-container div has no background-image so the parent or child is not sandwiched between them or something. the body is the one with the background. Also, there is no other parent-child that would be overlapping with the player.

Any insights would be appreciated thank you!

I have tried having a very high z-index for the child and z-index of parent is only 1, I have also tried the parent not having z-index at all. I also tried putting `Opacity:0.99;` in the parent class but same problem.

Comment: Try to give parent z-index in negative.

Comment: @sahilatahar i tried just now and it still has the same problem :(( i also tried putting opacity:0.99 with the negative z-index but still same problem

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it is due to the `background-position` applied in the `.player-sprite.up.stopped` rule:

[image: CSS rule]

If we take this into consideration with regards to the non-working instance and its background image:

[image: Sprite background image tooltip in Chrome devtools]

The `background-position` would reposition this background image outside the element, since the element and the background image is only 64 pixels × 64 pixels:

```
┌─────────┐─────
│ bg      │  ↑
│ image   │  │
│         │192px
└─────────┘  │
             │
             ↓
┏━━━━━━━━━┓─────
┃ visible ┃
┃ element ┃
┃ bounds  ┃
┗━━━━━━━━━┛
```

To resolve, consider setting the `background-position` to `0 0`, `center`, etc, to have the background image be visible:

```css
.player-sprite.up.stopped.gameover {
  background-position: center;
}
```